# Return json to browser via MVC controller for morris chart

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc

Program is written in .Net Framework 4.

Class:

```
public class yearsComparison
{
    public int year { get; set; }
    public string material1 { get; set; }
    public string material2 { get; set; }
    public string material3 { get; set; }
    public string material4 { get; set; }
    public string material5 { get; set; }
    public decimal value1 { get; set; }
    public decimal value2 { get; set; }
    public decimal value3 { get; set; }
    public decimal value4 { get; set; }
    public decimal value5 { get; set; }
    public string vendor1 { get; set; }
    public string vendor2 { get; set; }
    public string vendor3 { get; set; }
    public string vendor4 { get; set; }
    public string vendor5 { get; set; }
}
```

Code to change data into json, it will return top five over purchase material from current year and last year:

```
public ActionResult OverPurchaseToYear()
{
    var overPurchaseToYear = DAL.ReportHandler.GetOverPurchaseYearToYear(DateTime.Now.Year, 5);
    List<yearsComparison> chartData = new List<yearsComparison>();
    int index = 1;
    foreach (var item in overPurchaseToYear)
    {
        if (chartData.Where(x => x.year == item.forecastYear).Any())
        {
            yearsComparison temp = chartData.Where(x => x.year == item.forecastYear).FirstOrDefault();
            switch (index)
            {
                case 1:
                    temp.material1 = item.material;
                    temp.value1 = (decimal)item.overPurchaseQuantity;
                    temp.vendor1 = item.emVendor;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    temp.material2 = item.material;
                    temp.value2 = (decimal)item.overPurchaseQuantity;
                    temp.vendor2 = item.emVendor;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    temp.material3 = item.material;
                    temp.value3 = (decimal)item.overPurchaseQuantity;
                    temp.vendor3 = item.emVendor;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    temp.material4 = item.material;
                    temp.value4 = (decimal)item.overPurchaseQuantity;
                    temp.vendor4 = item.emVendor;
                    break;
                case 5:
                    temp.material5 = item.material;
                    temp.value5 = (decimal)item.overPurchaseQuantity;
                    temp.vendor5 = item.emVendor;
                    break;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            yearsComparison temp = new yearsComparison();
            temp.year = item.forecastYear;
            switch (index)
            {
                case 1:
                    temp.material1 = item.material;
                    temp.value1 = (decimal)item.overPurchaseQuantity;
                    temp.vendor1 = item.emVendor;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    temp.material2 = item.material;
                    temp.value2 = (decimal)item.overPurchaseQuantity;
                    temp.vendor2 = item.emVendor;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    temp.material3 = item.material;
                    temp.value3 = (decimal)item.overPurchaseQuantity;
                    temp.vendor3 = item.emVendor;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    temp.material4 = item.material;
                    temp.value4 = (decimal)item.overPurchaseQuantity;
                    temp.vendor4 = item.emVendor;
                    break;
                case 5:
                    temp.material5 = item.material;
                    temp.value5 = (decimal)item.overPurchaseQuantity;
                    temp.vendor5 = item.emVendor;
                    break;
            }
            chartData.Add(temp);
        }
        index++;
    }
    var json = chartData.ToArray();
    var jsonData = Json(json, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    return jsonData;
}
```

The json has to be in this format:

```
[
{"year":2018,"material1":"00-00012","material2":"00-00011","material3":"00-00010","material4":"00-00009","material5":"00-00008","value1":220.00,"value2":210.00,"value3":200.00,"value4":190.00,"value5":180.00,"vendor1":"12345","vendor2":"12345","vendor3":"12345","vendor4":"12345","vendor5":"12345"},
{"year":2017,"material1":"00-00012","material2":"00-00011","material3":"00-00010","material4":"00-00009","material5":"00-00008","value1":220.00,"value2":210.00,"value3":200.00,"value4":190.00,"value5":180.00,"vendor1":"12345","vendor2":"12345","vendor3":"12345","vendor4":"12345","vendor5":"12345"}
]
```

The generated chart will look like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/g3zohu5w/121/)

Code works but ugly, how can I improve it?

Answer (score 2):

The `switch` statement is repeated code that can be refactored into a single purpose function

```
private void populate(int index, MyItemType item, yearsComparison model) {
    switch (index) {
        case 1:
            model.material1 = item.material;
            model.value1 = (decimal)item.overPurchaseQuantity;
            model.vendor1 = item.emVendor;
            break;
        case 2:
            model.material2 = item.material;
            model.value2 = (decimal)item.overPurchaseQuantity;
            model.vendor2 = item.emVendor;
            break;
        case 3:
            model.material3 = item.material;
            model.value3 = (decimal)item.overPurchaseQuantity;
            model.vendor3 = item.emVendor;
            break;
        case 4:
            model.material4 = item.material;
            model.value4 = (decimal)item.overPurchaseQuantity;
            model.vendor4 = item.emVendor;
            break;
        case 5:
            model.material5 = item.material;
            model.value5 = (decimal)item.overPurchaseQuantity;
            model.vendor5 = item.emVendor;
            break;
    }
}
```

These 3 lines

```
var json = chartData.ToArray();
var jsonData = Json(json, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
return jsonData;
```

can be reduced to one line

```
return Json(chartData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

The former serves no real purpose as `List<T>` and `Array` serialize to the same JSON type.

The `Where` filter is also repeated unnecessarily on `chartData` when what you are actually checking for is if the item already exists in the collection.

With the suggested changes the action refactors to

```
public ActionResult OverPurchaseToYear() {
    var overPurchaseToYear = DAL.ReportHandler.GetOverPurchaseYearToYear(DateTime.Now.Year, 5);
    var chartData = new List<yearsComparison>();
    int index = 1;
    foreach (var item in overPurchaseToYear) {
        yearsComparison row = chartData.Where(x => x.year == item.forecastYear).FirstOrDefault();
        if (row != null) {
            populate(index, item, row);
        } else {
            row = new yearsComparison();
            row.year = item.forecastYear;
            populate(index, item, row);
            chartData.Add(row);
        }
        index++;
    }
    return Json(chartData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Most things are covered by @NKosi, so I won't repeat them. However you should consider this suggestion once you are done with changes suggested by him. So ideally this is not a complete answer but the continuation to what @NKosi said.

Your C# model violates the naming guidelines and it will not pass static code analysis. I understand the library you mentioned wont work with capitalized keys in `JSON` output. So what you can do is use `DataMember` or `JsonProperty` attribute on your model, use a serializer that support these properties and return result from custom JSON `ActionResult`. This way you will adhere to naming standard in `C#` as well as `JSON`.

See how you can write custom `ActionResult` for this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12497902/1440057